# Convert IQueryable<T> or LINQ query to unique string

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees, iqueryable

I have some LINQ query (or `IQueryable<T>` object based on LINQ query) and want to get some unique string based on this query.

I have, for example:

```
var someValue = 10;
var query = (from i in db.Customers
            where i.Id == someValue
            select i).AsQueryable();
```

I should get something like this:

> "from i in db.Customers where i.Id == 10"

I am trying to use Expression object and play with it but I can not get generic approach to get string with **exact** parameters values.

E.g.:

```
public string GetKey<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
{
  ...
  return unique_string;
}
```

Note that different parameters values for the same LINQ query should provide different strings.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suspect that this is simply not going to work. Aside from anything else, if you have to use `AsQueryable` (i.e. if your original query is over `IEnumerable<T>` then the compiler will have used delegates instead of expression trees to start with.

If it's a *pure* `IQuerable<T>` all the way, you could try using `query.Expression.ToString()`, but frankly it's not something I'd want to rely on.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue with [Expression Tree Serialization](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/exprserialization) with some improvements for getting exact values of passed parameters. It provides a big but *unique* XML file based on IQueryable objects.